# How to change the background color dynamically of the particular row of GridView in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am add rows in grid view dynamically as `listViewResult.Items.Add(new { Server = "test1", Value = "ABX", Availability = "Yes", Status = "No"});` 
At the same time i want to add the background color of the same row which i have added on the basis of Status Value. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a ListViewItem element directly:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Background = ... color you want ... ;
lvi.Content = new {Server = "test1", .... };
listViewResult.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Binding the Background to the Status will only work if Status is a DependencyProperty. If it's just a report and Status doesn't changed, there's no need to create a Binding, just set a color based on the Status' value.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this is to edit your ListViewItem's template and bind the Background property to the item's Status property using a converter to convert the status into a Brush/Color.

it's not as trivial as it may sound though...